# Running nicklist with irssi using screen inside tmux?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux, irssi

I try to run the nicklist addon with irssi using screen inside tmux but strangely :) it doesn't work and I get the input on top of the screen. Is it possible to run nicklist when you are on tmux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative way is splitting your current window in tmux (C-b + h or whatever you set up your shortcut) (horizontal), resize that window (C-b + left/right) and then activate nicklist.pl in the *"FIFO" way*:

**In irssi:**

- /NICKLIST FIFO (only the first time,
  to create the fifo)

**In a shell:**

- In the window we split and resize: $
  cat ~/.irssi/nicklistfifo

**Then in irssi again:**

- /SET nicklist_heigth "height of nicklist"
- /SET nicklist_width "width of nicklist"
- /NICKLIST FIFO

So at the end you should have:

## --------------------------|----------

## ---------irssi ----------   |nicklist

## --------------------------|----------

Comment: Finally tried tmux again and tested your solution and it seems to work well. Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: I used it some time, but it got too annoying with switching and scrolling so I dropped the nicklist windows and doesn't really miss it. Thanks anyways for a good answer!